# Countdown plugin is not working when im giving same year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a multiple event count down timer for an e-commerce website. It is working properly when I am using a the next year as YEAR Value (for example it is working with the date "02/05/2018 05:55:55" but not working when I'm using "02/07/2017 05:55:55")

```js
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
     $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.0.4/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1" data-countdown="01/01/2018 05:06:59"></div>
<div id="example2" data-countdown="01/07/2017"></div>
<div id="example3" data-countdown="01/01/2018"></div>
<div id="example4" data-countdown="05/07/2017"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to exchange month with day because the format is "month/day/year":

```
<div id="example1" data-countdown="01/01/2018 05:06:59"></div>
<div id="example2" data-countdown="07/01/2017"></div>
<div id="example3" data-countdown="01/01/2018"></div>
<div id="example4" data-countdown="07/05/2017"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3h9tyrvh/157/